# Environment variables accessible to jvm run from root

Tags: java, linux, runtime

I have a java application (run on Oracle Linux) that is run via an init script at boot as user root.  It would seem that the environment variables that are set are very basic.  They do not appear to be sourcing in the same environment variables that are brought in as the various system users, including root.  I am making a quick assumption that its because the java application is running Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command") is not in an interactive shell.  But even considering I may be correct, I have no idea how to get the java application to have access to the same environment variables the user has upon logon.

Comment: Shells typically get default values from configuration files in `/etc/` and `~`, and you can pass the required values to some versions of [`exec()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html). The details are platform- and shell-dependent. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: the exec() is running another program.  That program then runs a variety of other programs that load data into a database.  Where I'm getting stuck is that many of those data loading programs expect to have access to some environment variables, that they have access too when run from a shell, but they don't have access when run from the java program.  I've been getting around this by passing those environment variables explicitly in an array with the overloaded method Runtime.exec(string, env[], /dir), but I don't know all the variables that are needed and I keep having to recode.